# For loop logic to loop an image based by input value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, loops

Before i explain, here are the current codes:

```
function imageSource(source) {
    return "<img src='" + source + "' />";
}
function ImagetoPrint(title, source) {
    return "<html><head><script>function step1(){\n" +
            "setTimeout('step2()', 10);}\n" +
            "function step2(){window.print();window.close()}\n" +
            "</scri" + "pt></head><body onload='step1()'>\n" +
            "<h3>" + title + "</h3>" +
            imageSource(source) + "</body></html>";
}
function PrintImage(title, source) {
    Pagelink = "about:blank";
    var qty = $("#qrQty").val();
    var pwa = window.open(Pagelink, "_new");
    for (var i = 1; i <= qty; i++) {
        imageSource(source);
    }
    pwa.document.open();
    pwa.document.write(ImagetoPrint(title, source));
    pwa.document.close();
}
```

I want to loop the imageSource function which get called through the ImagetoPrint function, and the ImagetoPrint function get called through the PrintImage function.

Sounds confusing, but what i'm trying to do is i'm trying to loop the image based on the value of input id of "qrQty", for example if the value of "qrQty" is 3, the image is looping 3 times.

Comment: The `for` loop doesn’t do anything because you just call `imageSource` and discard the return value `qty` times. You need to actually embed the return value into the generated page. It would be also nice if you escaped the tag contents, in case someone wishes to `PrintImage("", "\" onerror=\"alert('where is your god now?');");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, by declaring a new var with empty quotes and then add it inside for loop

```
function ImagetoPrint(title, source) {
    return "<html><head><script>function step1(){\n" +
            "setTimeout('step2()', 10);}\n" +
            "function step2(){window.print();window.close()}\n" +
            "</scri" + "pt></head><body onload='step1()'>\n" +
            "<h3>" + title + "</h3>" +
            source + "</body></html>";
}
function PrintImage(title, source) {
    Pagelink = "about:blank";
    var qty = $("#qrQty").val();
    var pwa = window.open(Pagelink, "_new");
    var img = "";
    for (var i = 1; i <= qty; i++) {
        var img = img+"<img src='" + source + "' />";
    }
    pwa.document.open();
    pwa.document.write(ImagetoPrint(title, img));
    pwa.document.close();
}
```